# python multiple x vs y line plots with unique z values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bokeh

I've got a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Iteration    output          Temperature
1            23                 -40
1            26                  -7 
1            20                  25 
1            30                  78
2            34                 -40
2            33                  -7 
2            32                  25 
2            36                  78 
3            34                 -40
3            37                  -7 
3            45                  25 
3            43                  78
```

I want to get multiple line plots of output(y) vs temperature (x) for unique iteration values.

For the example data, I would get three overlaid line plots, for the three unique iteration values.

How do I do this in python?

Do I get a list of unique iteration values and then use that to filter out the dataframe and individually plot them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for group,records in df.groupby('iteration'):
    plt.plot(records['output'],records['temperature'],legend=str(group))
```

Is how i would probably do it

Comment: Thanks! this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Followup, how do i get the iteration number that each line plot corresponds to?

Comment: @lonely see edit ... should add legend entries (you probably need to enable the legend with `plt.legend()` before you call `show`

Comment: Thanks a lot. got the legends now.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g=sns.FacetGrid(df, row='Iteration')
g=g.map(plt.scatter, 'Temperature', 'output')
plt.show()
```

If you want the 3 lines in the same plot, this is the code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.lineplot(df['Temperature'], df['output'], hue=df['Iteration'])
plt.show()
```